# Is there a way to only show EUR currency in my paypal transactions?

Tags: paypal

My transactions look kinda like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iK4CI.png) now:

[image]

displaying both euro and usd

Is there a way for it to only display Euro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can change your account's primary currency so all transactions are automatically transferred to your choice.

https://www.paypal.com/us/selfhelp/article/How-do-I-change-my-primary-currency-FAQ1030

Comment: When logged in the link directs me to a page saying it's no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

When logged in to PayPal you click the activity button on the top left and there

[activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPn0K.png)

It displays all the transactions with an option for currency.

[currencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcQVh.png)

However this doesn't change all curencies on my transactions page, nor does it remember the chosen currency.